# Every 16th call of swiftmailer:spool:send ends up with STMP timeout

Tags: symfony, smtp, timeout, swiftmailer, spool

I use file spool in my Symfony2.2 project. I flush spool every minut with cron.

An error occurs every 16 minutes with an accuracy of a few seconds: e.g. 14:38:31, 14:54:31, 15:14:31, 15:30:31. etc.

```
[12-Aug-2013 16:02:31 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Swift_IoException' with message 'Connection to mail.mydomain.pl:25 Timed Out' in /home/projectname/test.projectname.pl/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php:169
```

Here's stack trace:

```
Stack trace:
#0 /home/projectname/test.projectname.pl/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(400): Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->readLine(NULL)
#1 /home/projectname/test.projectname.pl/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(277): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_getFullResponse(NULL)
#2 /home/projectname/test.projectname.pl/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/EsmtpTransport.php(245): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->executeCommand('QUIT??', Array, Array)
#3 /home/projectname/test.projectname.pl/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(217): Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport->executeCommand('QUIT??', Array)
#4 /home/projectname/test.projectname.pl/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/ in /home/projectname/test.projectname.pl/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php on line 169
```

I'm out of ideas and do not know what I can check next.

Maybe there is a connection limit to the server, but do not know how to check it out. Besides - should not swiftmailer:spool:send close the connection after execution?

This is the command from cron:

```
/home/projectname/test.projectname.pl/app/console swiftmailer:spool:send
```

UPDATE: It was due to smtp server provider.

Comment: Which server? Try to reduce your cron to every second minute

Comment: Server address is mail.e-surf.pl:25 . I can reduce frequency of calls to every 2 minutes, but only for diagnostic purposes. I don't think that I was able to convince my manager to reduce the frequency of mail delivery. I'll let You know about the result.

Comment: You should contact your mail provider. Maybe your are only allowed to make limited connections in a time span.